# Migrate from EJB 2 Entity Bean to EJB3

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, ejb-2.x, entity-bean

I am having some entity beans created in EJB 2.0 and now I need to migrate to EJB 3.x, but I've studied that use of entity beans are changed in EJB 3.x and they are using JPA instead.

Where can I find solution to actuate my beans to be comfortable with EJB 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example from following resources available online:

- http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/ejb/ejb3_migration.htm
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/oc4j-twp-ejb3-migration-1013-133021.pdf

or following printed books:

- Pro JPA 2 Mastering the Java Persistence API (p. 457-466)
- EJB3 in Action (p. 513-528)

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ EJB refactoring tools might prove to be useful: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/migrating-to-ejb-3-0.html

I belive there are some for Eclipse too.

Answer (score 0):

just for future reference, I recommend the following link:
http://what-when-how.com/enterprise-javabeans-3/migrating-cmp-2-entity-beans-to-the-ejb-3-jpa-part-1/

And there's also part 2 on the same site as well as migrating session beans and MDBs.
I used them and found them very helpful and useful.